# command error(dcos client) against DCOS Cluster

Tags: certificate, client, mesos, dcos

Finding a solution to get out from this issue.

I've installed DC/OS 1.10 cluster using seven VMs.
Role of each VMs(one bootstrap-node, three mesos-masters, three mesos slaves, OS: ubuntu16.04)

No errors while installation.
The cluster is configured well and also installed client(dcos) to manage cluster through terminal.

When I execute below command

```
dcos cluster setup http://*.*.*.4
```

I got message next line.

```
Error downloading CA certificate from cluster. Please check the provided DC/OS URL
```

This is my `config.yaml` that i use for installation.
[image]

Any opinions & comments are ok

Thanks you in advance.

Tombart

This is the result of "systemctl list-units dcos*"
and also attached two pictures.
[image]
[image]

How can i resolve this issue? dcos cluster setup http://*.*.*.*

Yes,I'm using DC/OS(opensource, followed by this https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/installing/custom/)

As you can see my config.yaml.
I add internal dns service with google dns as well.

## This is the output regarding spartan service on one of mesos-masters

Oct 23 09:16:34 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.28886.50>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 09:23:09 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [error] <0.869.0> Lager event handler error_logger_lager_h exited with reason {'EXIT',{{badmatch,[<0.31575.50>,{info,{'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.2097153.96391>,process,<0.31578.50>,noproc}},{wait_for_query,{state,#Por
Oct 23 09:44:40 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.7478.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:00:09 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.13739.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:00:10 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.13775.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:00:10 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.13766.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:00:40 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.13976.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:00:40 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.13971.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:03:15 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.15053.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:03:15 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.15058.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:07:55 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.17068.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:07:55 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.17066.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:08:58 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.17501.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:08:59 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.17509.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:08:59 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.17508.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa
Oct 23 10:10:54 m-abb20479 spartan-env[11898]: [warning] <0.18307.51>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spa

## this is output from one of mesos-slaves

Oct 23 10:02:05 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.934.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spart
Oct 23 10:02:05 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.953.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spart
Oct 23 10:02:05 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.838.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spart
Oct 23 10:02:05 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.976.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spart
Oct 23 10:08:46 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [error] <0.869.0> Lager event handler error_logger_lager_h exited with reason {'EXIT',{{badmatch,[<0.3854.39>,{info,{'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.3670017.105535>,process,<0.3898.39>,noproc}},{wait_for_query,{state,#Port
Oct 23 10:08:46 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [error] <0.3854.39> Ranch listener {spartan_tcp_listener,{198,51,100,1}} terminated with reason: function_clause
Oct 23 10:10:35 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.4615.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:10:35 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.4586.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:11:13 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.4895.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:14:25 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.6245.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,4,4},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:14:25 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.6292.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:16:29 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.7159.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:22:31 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [warning] <0.9709.39>@spartan_handler_fsm:resolve:225 Resolver ({{8,8,8,8},53}) Process exited: normal stacktrace [{spartan_handler_fsm,do_resolve,3,[{file,"/pkg/src/spartan/_build/prod/lib/spartan/src/spar
Oct 23 10:29:17 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [error] <0.869.0> Lager event handler error_logger_lager_h exited with reason {'EXIT',{{badmatch,[<0.12567.39>,{info,{'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.3670017.122650>,process,<0.12573.39>,noproc}},{wait_for_query,{state,#Po
Oct 23 10:29:17 s-0c35686e spartan-env[11468]: [error] <0.12567.39> Ranch listener {spartan_tcp_listener,{198,51,100,2}} terminated with reason: function_clause

Answer (score 1):

First of all Ubuntu is not between supported systems. I'd be surprised if the installation would be completed successfully. For [installing DC/OS on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789566/dc-os-on-gce-ubuntu/45879097#45879097) some extra steps are necessary.

What is the output of following command on any master node?

```
systemctl list-units dcos*
```

Are all services running? If you open `http://*.*.*.4` in a browser, do you see login screen? Have you followed [all steps in DC/OS install guide](https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/installing/custom/cli/)?